# reading only some strings from a file and storing it in stack in java

Tags: java, file, collections, while-loop, stack

the file is:

```
The Lord Of the Rings
J.R.R. Tolkein
Great Expectations
Charles Dickens
Green Eggs and Ham
Dr. Seuss
Tom Sawyer
Mark Twain
Moby Dick
Herman Melville
The Three Musketeers
Alexander Dumas
The Hunger Games
Suzanne Collins
1984
George Orwell
Gone With the Wind
Margret Mitchell
Life of Pi
Yann Martel
```

It has the title of the book in first line and in the next line it has author.

I only want to read first five books and authors from the file and then store it in a stack. Add the first two books with author in a stack and then remove the last one. How can I do it?
This is what I did

```
Stack<Book> readingList = new Stack<>();



    File myFile = new File("books.txt");
    Scanner input = new Scanner(myFile);
    int i = 0;
    while (input.hasNext()) {
        readingList.push(new Book(input.nextLine(), input.nextLine()));
      System.out.println("Adding: " + readingList.lastElement().getInfo());
        readingList.push(new Book(input.nextLine(), input.nextLine()));
      System.out.println("Adding: " + readingList.lastElement().getInfo());
        System.out.println("Reading:  " + readingList.pop().getInfo());
    }
```

Comment: And what is the problem with your code?

Comment: I don't know how to read only 5 books. This thing is reading the whole file

Comment: use the `break` statement if i=5

Comment: Yes thank you that works.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Asumming that every Book + Author is in one line of your file:

to read only the first five books use a `for-loop` instead of `while`:

```
     Stack<Book> readingList = new Stack<>();



                            File myFile = new File("books.txt");
                            Scanner input = new Scanner(myFile);
                            int i = 0;
                            int counter = 0;
                            for (int numberOfBookToRead = 0; numberOfBookToRead < 2;numberOfBookToRead++) {
                                try {
                                    if(readingList.hasNextLine() && counter <= 4){ // provides that only 4 books are pushed while the iteration is going, and also works 
                                       readingList.push(new Book(input.nextLine(), input.nextLine()));
                                       counter += 1;
                                       System.out.println("Adding: " + readingList.lastElement().getInfo());
                                       readingList.push(new Book(input.nextLine(), input.nextLine()));
                                       counter +=1;
                                       System.out.println("Adding: " + readingList.lastElement().getInfo());
                                       System.out.println("Reading:  " + readingList.pop().getInfo());
                                       readingList.pop() = null;
                                    }catch(Exception e){
                                          e.printStackTrace();
                                     }
                                } else if(readingList.hasNextLine){
                                          readingList.push(new Book(input.nextLine(), input.nextLine()));
                                          System.out.println("Adding: " + readingList.lastElement().getInfo());
                                        }
                            }
```

afterwards to clear the last item from stack:

```
    readingList.pop() = null;
```

Because i got a lot of time. Here is the same function but with a variable number of maximum books:

```
Stack<Book> readingList = new Stack<>();



                            File myFile = new File("books.txt");
                            Scanner input = new Scanner(myFile);
                            int i = 0;
                            int counter = 0;
                            int maxNumberOfBooks = 10; //could be any number you wish
                            for (int numberOfBookToRead = 0; numberOfBookToRead < Math.round(maxNumberOfBooks/2)-1;numberOfBookToRead++) {
                                try {
                                    if(readingList.hasNextLine() && counter <= maxNumberOfBooks-1){
                                       readingList.push(new Book(input.nextLine(), input.nextLine()));
                                       counter += 1;
                                       System.out.println("Adding: " + readingList.lastElement().getInfo());
                                       readingList.push(new Book(input.nextLine(), input.nextLine()));
                                       counter +=1;
                                       System.out.println("Adding: " + readingList.lastElement().getInfo());
                                       System.out.println("Reading:  " + readingList.pop().getInfo());
                                       readingList.pop() = null;
                                    }catch(Exception e){
                                          e.printStackTrace();
                                     }
                                } else if(readingList.hasNextLine){
                                          readingList.push(new Book(input.nextLine(), input.nextLine()));
                                          System.out.println("Adding: " + readingList.lastElement().getInfo());
                                        }
                            }
```

Comment: That gives errors if the file only contains 4 books

Comment: ok i edit it, well thats easy. Ok now he only reads the line if he got a next one :D How about this :P

Comment: Yes it would. We could just do a try catch for that and it should be good to go

Comment: Wait, the question was that it would add two and then remove one. its adding one and removing one. This is the output:

/*Adding: J.R.R. Tolkein by The Lord Of the Rings
Reading:  J.R.R. Tolkein by The Lord Of the Rings
Adding: Charles Dickens by Great Expectations
Reading:  Charles Dickens by Great Expectations
Adding: Dr. Seuss by Green Eggs and Ham
Reading:  Dr. Seuss by Green Eggs and Ham
Adding: Mark Twain by Tom Sawyer
Reading:  Mark Twain by Tom Sawyer
Adding: Herman Melville by Moby Dick
Reading:  Herman Melville by Moby Dick
BUILD SUCCESSFUL (total time: 0 seconds)*/

Comment: Well no problem just add another book in your for-loop. Its edited Im sorry that I cant test it myself :P

Comment: That's exactly what it did and since it is adding 2 books at one time and the loop is running 5 times, it would actually print the whole thing.
I cant give the output because its too long

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/90955/discussion-between-tom-wellbrock-and-dragon).

Answer (score 0):

You might want to check for exceptions, in case of a bad file

```
Stack<Book> readingList = new Stack<>();
File myFile = new File("books.txt");
Scanner input = new Scanner(myFile);

for (int count = 0; count < 5; count++) {

    try {
        readingList.push(new Book(input.nextLine(), input.nextLine()));
        System.out.println("Adding: " + readingList.lastElement().getInfo());
        System.out.println("Reading:  " + readingList.pop().getInfo());
    }
    catch(Exception e) {

        System.out.println(e.getMessage());
    }
}
```

Comment: That is a helpfull comment but not an answere. If your file is bigger than 5 lines your code wont do. Also after every second book, the book should be cleared from stack